# Git merge/rebase from main adds files to PR

Tags: git, azure, pull-request

I have been having this issue for a while. While working on a feature branch with a PR open (using Azure web here), sometimes I want to bring changes *main* to test properly.

However, doing `git rebase origin/main` or `git merge origin/main` and pushing to my branch results in the PR showing the changes I brought from main as live/new changes.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is the PR target branch `main`, or some other branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can check few things in your `Azure DevOps` repos settings,

1. check if your target branch is set to `master` branch.
2. check if the `compare` branch is set to `master` branch since you're comparing changes against it.